# SQL Date interval not working with AND clause

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I am trying to count views in time interval. The request below works only without the `AND` clause

If I take out the `AND s.timestamp < 2019-01-31` it works just fine.

```
SELECT s.category_id, c.name, count(s.category_id) AS ViewCount 
FROM stat_product_category s 
JOIN category c ON s.category_id = c.id 
WHERE s.timestamp > 2019-01-01 AND s.timestamp < 2019-01-31
GROUP BY s.category_id 
ORDER By ViewCount Desc 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and output data, and tell us what the error is.

Comment: it should give error because of `c.name` ,in the select list , which's not in `group by`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan full group by mode is disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need single quote on date value

```
SELECT s.category_id, c.name, count(s.category_id) AS ViewCount 
FROM stat_product_category s 
JOIN category c ON s.category_id = c.id 
WHERE s.timestamp > '2019-01-01' AND s.timestamp <'2019-01-31'
GROUP BY s.category_id ,c.name
ORDER By ViewCount Desc 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: There are so many syntax/logical errors that I might refrain from answering just yet.

Comment: thanks that solved it but I don't get why it would work without quotes if I don't have the and ? will accept asap

Comment: @Sam without quotes those values are not converted into date data type value that's the reason

Comment: @Sam . . . It doesn't "work".  It just returns all the timestamps.  I doubt it is doing the filtering that you intend.

Comment: I tested it with sequel pro and in my project (via doctrine) and it definitely works without quotes if I omit the AND.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't timestamps - without quotes, you just have a couple of ints you're subtracting. 2019-01-01 is evaluated as 2019-1-1, or 2017. 2019-01-31 is evaluated as 2019-1-31, or 1987. There is no number that's greater than 2017 but smaller than 1987, so you get no results. Surrounding these values with quotes will make them a string literal, and allow the database to perform an implicit conversion to a date:

```
SELECT s.category_id, c.name, count(s.category_id) AS ViewCount 
FROM stat_product_category s 
JOIN category c ON s.category_id = c.id 
WHERE s.timestamp > '2019-01-01' AND s.timestamp < '2019-01-31'
-- Here ------------^----------^-------------------^----------^
GROUP BY s.category_id 
ORDER By ViewCount Desc 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

that script is looking good you just need to pop qoutes around your dates so that SQL knows where the values start & stops.

```
SELECT s.category_id, c.name, count(s.category_id) AS ViewCount 
FROM stat_product_category s 
JOIN category c ON s.category_id = c.id 
WHERE s.timestamp > '2019-01-01' AND s.timestamp < '2019-01-31'
GROUP BY s.category_id 
ORDER By ViewCount Desc 
LIMIT 10
```

(tested & working!)

Good luck with the project!

Comment: -1 why??? Please comment if something is not clear but I don't think I really could have put it any simpler "just add apostrophes either side of your values".

Comment: . . I didn't downvote.  Perhaps someone thought that the other two answers were sufficient.

Comment: okie doke .. well I guess some people are just rude :) I was off testing this when the others posted there's so no need for them to get upset >hehe<